# How would I replace all question marks after the first

Tags: php, regex

So, a lot of my form systems redirect back to the previous page, although, they display a message in the process. The way I display a message is by simply using `?message=messageCode` in the `URL`.

However, if they use the form from a page that already has a query string, it adds a second query string, messing everything up.

Example:
if I were to login from the navigation bar, on the `URL` "`mywebsite.com/something?message=1`", it would log in, but redirect to "`mywebsite.com/something?message=1?message=2`"

This results in no message being displayed.

What I am asking here is, how could I change all of the question marks AFTER the first question mark, to and signs?

Example:
From: `mywebsite.com/page?blah=1?something=2?hi=3`
To: `mywebsite.com/page?blah=1&something=2&hi=3`

I have searched around, as well as tried some methods of my own, but nothing seems to work properly.

Comment: [instead of using a regex for this, you should be properly building the redirect url.](http://php.net/http_build_query)

Comment: Would it not be easier to replace all of  them and then change the first one back to a '?'. E.G  $a = 'mywebsite.com/page?blah=1?something=2?hi=3';
echo preg_replace( '/&/' , '?' , str_replace ( '?' , '&' , $a) ,1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like below:-

```
<?php
   $str = 'mywebsite.com/something?message=1?message=2';
   $pos = strpos($str,'?'); //check the last occurrence of ?
   if ($pos !== false) {
       $str = substr($str,0,$pos+1) . str_replace('?','&',substr($str,$pos+1));// replacement of ? to &
   }
  echo $str;
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/388308

Comment: Done. Was waiting for the timer to ware off.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is build a proper URL, appending `?` or `&` when appropriate.

```
$url = 'mywebsite.com/something?message=1';
$new_url = sprintf('%s%s%s', 
    $url, 
    strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&',
    http_build_query(['message' => 2])
);
```

Or, first parse the previous URL and merge the query string.